# how to restrict Java method invocation only for 1st occurance of any event?

Tags: java, methods, invoke

Made a workaround by making addButton return a boolean (which is true when clicked and false when not) then I did this: `if (addButton)
{
doSomething();
}`

(Sorry, title can be misleading. Couldn't make up a better title)

I got this method (lets call it method1, it is also called all the time in the loop) which adds a custom button, and I want that button to (when clicked) run a specified method(lets call it method2) only once. I want method1 to be used in several different classes but to trigger different actions.

```
public void addButton(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, AttributedCharacterIterator atstr, Method method)
{
    BufferedImage img = Sprites.button;

    x -=img.getWidth()/2;
    y -=img.getHeight()/2;
    int border = 10;

    g2d.drawImage(img, null, x, y);
    g2d.drawString(atstr, x + (img.getWidth()/2) - border, y + (img.getHeight()/2) + 10);
    Rectangle getBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    if (MouseInput.getBounds().intersects(getBounds) && MouseInput.mouseClickedPressed == true)
    {
        try {
            method.invoke(this);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It is called like this:

```
addButton(g2d, 200, 200, Template.atstr(g2d, "Siege!", Color.BLACK, "Times New Roman", 20, doSomething()));
        public Method doSomething()
        {
            //Action.....
            return null;
        }
```

My problem is that method2 is called all the time and I've figured why,but is there any way around?

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I've read and re-read your question several times, and I'm still very confused as to your goals and your problem.

Comment: where is your `method2`?

Comment: I would give you suggestions but already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to be invoked only once, you need flag / field `boolean invoked` that will be set to `true` when invoked first time, and will prevent from being invoked later - just write some if: `if(!invoked) { invoke... }`

Comment: I want it to be invoked only when clicked, not when addButton is called(which is called every time the game updates)

Comment: @user1658294 that does not change anything in my sollution, except of potential place, where that particular `if` should be placed

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, when trying to outprint the boolean outside the method it's always false, but when it's inside; it turns true. Could you please post your solution to pastebin and link it here, maybe I just misunderstood you.

Comment: nvm, made a workaround by making addButton return a boolean (turns true when clicked) so if (addbutton){doSomething()}....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code and failed... 
However I believe that I can recommend you to create special flag, (e.g. `buttonClicked`). The value of this variable will be `false`.

When user clicks button the flow should arrive to code like this:

```
if (buttonClicked) {
    return;
}
buttonClicked = true;
// do other stuff hrere
```

Please do not forget to synchronize this piece of code. Otherwise it could be executed simultaneously if user clicks fast enough.

Comment: Well, you could double-hit it while the JVM is busy running the garbage collector or CPU is busy doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need a flag variable, which is set when method 2 runs. an put a check for method2 `if(!flag) method2();`